# Missed User property, for counting number of user/roles in asp.net core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, role-manager

### Scenario:

I have an Asp.net core program that using identity authentication.

### Goal:

I want to get number of users that have specific role like this:

```
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

    public RoleController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<roleListViewModel> model = new List<roleListViewModel>();
        model = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new roleListViewModel
        {
            id = r.Id,
            Name = r.Name,
            Description = r.Description,
            NumberOfUsers = r.User.count

        }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

### The problem is:

I couldn't find **User** in `NumberOfUsers = r.User.count` line.

#### Role Model:

```
public class ApplicationRole:IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

#### Role View Model:

```
public class roleListViewModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name can not empty")]
    [Display(Name ="Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfUsers { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Description can not empty")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

#### View Index:

```
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name</td>
                    <td>@item.Description</td>
                    <td>@item.NumberOfUsers</td>
                </tr>
            }
```

## Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

This for all roles.

```
var allUserRoles = _identityDb.UserRoles.ToList();
model = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new roleListViewModel
{
    Id = r.Id,
    Name = r.Name,
    Description = r.Description,
    NumberOfUsers = allUserRoles.Count(ur => ur.RoleId == r.Id)
}).ToList();
```

For special role

```
var usersBySpecialRole = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("myRole").Result;
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but is there any way to didn't use **UserRoles** Table and lambda expressions, and just use this line **NumberOfUsers = r.User.count**?

Comment: sorry dude, but I don't know this way now